# Mysql group_concat adds a separator for empty fields

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

There is a sample schema in here: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0723a/2

query is `select id,group_concat(val) from test group by id`

result is

> ID    GROUP_CONCAT(VAL) 
>  1    ,64,66,,203,214,204

I wanted to concat val field without a comma for empty records like this

> ID    GROUP_CONCAT(VAL) 
>  1    64,66,203,214,204

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use **Replace**

```
select id,replace(group_concat(val),',,',',') from test group by id
```

Or you can use **IF**

```
select id,group_concat(if(val ='',null, val)) from test group by id
```

Or You can use **NULLIF**

```
select id,group_concat(Nullif(val,'')) from test group by id
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0723a/11)**

Comment: @xdazz Thanks for your comment. I have added alternative way too

Comment: NULLIF run faster than IF on my complex query. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(val) FROM test 
WHERE val is not null AND val <> '' 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer. it's simple and more accurate

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct, if there is no any other field in the query. But, when i want to select the records even if the val field is null it is not correct

Answer (score 1):

Add an `IF` check, `GROUP_CONCAT` will skip the `NULL` value.

```
select id, group_concat(IF(val = '', null, val)) from test group by id
```

**[THE SQLFIDDLE.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0723a/3)**